# I cannot browse and run the applications

Tags: startup-applications

My "applications(icon)" is not working. i used to browse and run the applications simply clicking on it.This time nothing appears.Somebody help me,please.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot please. Are you using Unity or something else ?

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
                - the Lucid Lynx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 10.04 you are very likely to use gnome2. The old good time :-)

To reset the menu bar, open a terminal and simply type

```
$ gnome-panel
```

That should reset your menu bar.

If it complains about a gnome-panel already running, just kill the related process.

```
$ killall gnome-panel
```